# Tomcat does not allow URL with %00, is there a switch to turn off the check?

Tags: tomcat

I am using Servlet and tomcat to build an HTTP Middleware that intercepts HTTP requests, logs them, and probably rewrites them.

I notice that when the request URL contains `%00` like the following:
`/channel/%00List%0000001%00`
Tomcat will just return 400 without calling my Servlet. Is there a configuration to change this behavior? I have used `encodedSolidusHandling="passthrough"` for the connector, but it seems that it only works for characters like `%2B` and `%2F`, but not for `%00`

Comment: %00 equals a NULL character, "ASCII"-code 0, which most likely is "End of string" for the software encountering it in "native" / "binary" form (i.e. not the string  of characters inside quotes: "%00"). i.e `/channel/%00List%0000001%00` translates to `/channel/` if so, try it out, get the same answer there?

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. The target system (CouchDB) accepts NULL in its key and actually stores the corresponding data as follows `\u0000List\u000000001\u0000`. You can see it stores NULL as part of the key.

Comment: Is that NULL sourced from the outside? i.e. from an external source; I'd still wager there is a problem with this, unless some thoughtful consideration has gone into the code that is running.

Comment: It is from the outside. My middleware goes in between a blockchain system called HyperLedger Fabric and a database of CouchDB. HyperLedger Fabric seems to use NULL as a separator between components of the keys. When I do a query in Fabric with a composite key `["List","00001"]`, Fabric turns it into an URL `%00 List %00 00001 %00` then send the query against CouchDB. There are many different separators but I have no idea why they use %00.